# Android OneSignal notification cant open "Closed" application

Tags: java, android, onesignal

I'm receiving notifications using OneSignal, if my app was in the background, and I click on the came notification, the app opening normally as I wanted going to the requested activity without any problem! 
But if the app was not running i mean totally closed, after tapping the notification nothing happening at all! app not opening! notification going away without opening the app! any advice?

Here is the code i'm using to handle OneSignal notifications

```
 private class NotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
    // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it.
    @Override
    public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
        OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
        JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
        String launchUrl = result.notification.payload.launchURL; // update docs launchUrl
        String body = result.notification.payload.body; // update docs launchUrl

        String customKey;
        String openURL = null;
        Object activityToLaunch = MainActivity.class;

        if (data != null) {
            customKey = data.optString("customkey", null);
            openURL = data.optString("openURL", null);

            if (customKey != null)
                Log.i("OneSignalExample", "customkey set with value: " + customKey);

            if (openURL != null)
                Log.i("OneSignalExample", "openURL to webview with URL value: " + openURL);
        }

        if (actionType == OSNotificationAction.ActionType.ActionTaken) {
            Log.i("OneSignalExample", "Button pressed with id: " + result.action.actionID);

            if (result.action.actionID.equals("id1")) {
                Log.i("OneSignalExample", "button id called: " + result.action.actionID);
                activityToLaunch = Notifications.class;
            } else
                Log.i("OneSignalExample", "button id called: " + result.action.actionID);
        }
        // The following can be used to open an Activity of your choice.

        Intent toActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Notifications.class);
        toActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        toActivity.putExtra("openURL", launchUrl);

        toActivity.putExtra("body", body);

        Log.i("OneSignalExample", "openURL = " + launchUrl);

        //my Code
        String message;
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(NOTES, Context
                .MODE_PRIVATE);
        String jsonLink = sharedPreferences.getString(NOTES_LINKS, null);
        String jsonTitle = sharedPreferences.getString(NOTES_TITLE, null);

        if (jsonLink != null && jsonTitle != null) {

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            ArrayList<String> linkList = gson.fromJson(jsonLink, new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {
            }.getType());

            ArrayList<String> titleList = gson.fromJson(jsonTitle, new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {
            }.getType());

            if (linkList.contains(launchUrl)) {
                message = "Notification Exist!";
                Log.i("Notifications","Notification Exist!");

            } else {
                linkList.add(launchUrl);
                titleList.add(body.trim());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(NOTES_LINKS, new Gson().toJson(linkList));
                editor.putString(NOTES_TITLE, new Gson().toJson(titleList));
                editor.apply();

                Log.i("Notifications","Notification Stored!");

            }
        } else {

            ArrayList<String> linkList = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();
            linkList.add(launchUrl);
            titleList.add(body.trim());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(NOTES_LINKS, new Gson().toJson(linkList));
            editor.putString(NOTES_TITLE, new Gson().toJson(titleList));
            editor.apply();

            Log.i("Notifications","Stored");

        }
        // startActivity(intent);
        startActivity(toActivity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am just digging for another issue with onesignal notification, and found this question, 
I would like to answer like:

what value have you set for NotificationOpened.DEFAULT in Manifest.

"Enable" will open your application.

```
<application>   <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT" android:value="Enable" /></application>
```

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same issue before and was able to solve it by creating an application class and initializing oneSignal in it

```
    public class Application extends android.app.Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // OneSignal Initialization
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new NotificationHandler(this))
                .init();
    }
}
```

you also need to add these in your manifist

```
<application 
   android:name="Application"
   ...>
    <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT" android:value="DISABLE" />
</application>
```